# Extend java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, inheritance

java.lang.String is declared as final, however are there any mechanisms available legitimate or otherwise to extend it and replace the equals(String other) method?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this?

Comment: I was wondering about the same some time ago, and the only answer I got was to wrap a String to other class and use this other class instead. (un)fortunately, final class is a final class :)

Comment: Making `String` `final` was a very deliberate decision on the part of the JDK's authors ;)

Comment: From SCJP Book: `If programmers were free to extend the String class, civilization - as we know it - could collapse.`

Comment: But there are good reasons to *want* to extend String. Many things are a String with extra restrictions/conditions. Your password is a string, but not every string is suitable as a password (legal characters etc). I think Scala allows you to subtype String?

Comment: The SCJP book sucks. Either give us a real reason or just don't mention it. I for one have had many use cases for extending String... Or at least being able to create a `MyClass` and then be able to do `MyClass = 'My String'`. Also there are languages that *do* allow you to override / create your own String classes... C++ springs to mind. I'm not saying I like C++ string handling (*au contraire*), but it's not like civilization has collapsed due to it.

Comment: Class `javax.script.SimpleBindings` has a method `putAll(Map<? extends String,? extends Object>)`. If there was a sound reason to make `String` final, then what the heck is this signature good for?

Comment: Why you can't extend java.lang.String (the real reason).  When string is created a hash is used to store that String in the java.lang.Object pool table (where all Java Objects are stored).  If two strings have the same hash, only one is stored and the reference to that one storage is incremented.  So, changing the String or the hash, in only one reference damages the map to that object.

Comment: My reason currently for wanting to extend is that I have a lot of generic collections using a String. I can put the context for that string value in the name of the variable but being able to provide an alias for the type would be helpful similar to scala traits

Answer (score 38):

No, absolutely not. If you want some "other" kind of string, create another type which might *contain* a string:

```
public final class OtherString {
    private final String underlyingString;

    public OtherString(String underlyingString) {
        this.underlyingString = underlyingString;
    }        

    // Override equals however you want here
}
```

Comment: But **String s="hi";** is doable, but not **OtherString s="hi";**

Comment: @everlasto: Sure. You'd have to write `OtherString s = new OtherString("hi");`

Comment: I have a question.. if implement this, maybe have problems with memory ?

Comment: @marlonpya: That question is too vague to answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: :D.
I just want to know if I would have problems, for instantiating many times

Comment: @marlonpya: No more or less than with any other class you create.

Comment: @JonSkeet There is a problem with the "OtherString" method that I'd like to avoid.  The introduction of an extra object pointer.  When dealing with millions of strings, the dramatically affects processing performance.    String -> one object pointer.

Comment: @DavidUrry: Yes, additional abstractions often have performance trade-offs. Although as it's only an extra reference rather than duplicating data, it's not like it's going to double the memory size. If you have a very specific situation then there may be other options, but they really will depend on what your *exact* requirements are.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've been working on Java since being part of the team at SUN that did the first commercially viable Java Apps.  I think that the String programmers missed it.  Boynton, van Hoff, Buchholz and Zibiz made a mistake.  They could have protected the uniqueness with "import final" while still allowing String to be extensible.

Comment: @DavidUrry: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I value the fact that I know string is immutable and its behaviour is well-defined due to it being final. I think the value of that for the majority of programmers outweighs the relatively small number of situations where being extensible would be of benefit. I readily acknowledge that's a matter of opinion though.

Comment: @JonSkeet it seems to me that making string immutable ("private final byte[] value;" java.lang.String:140) is not the same thing as making String non-extensible ("public final class String" java.lang.String:125).  Just because someone figured out one way does not mean it's the only way.

Comment: @DavidUrry: If someone can extend `String`, they can create a subclass that is immutable. Making the *text* of the string immutable is not the same as the whole object being immutable. It would mean that if I receive a `String` object, I still don't know whether or not it's immutable. (And if the purpose were to be able to override `equals`, I wouldn't even know if that aspect were immutable. I could add it as the key in a HashMap and then find out that its equality rules had been changed afterwards. Yikes!)

Comment: @JonSkeet I solved this today.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193450/how-do-you-extend-java-lang-string.  It's possible to do: 

    MyClass extends Strings {
    byte[] value;
    ...
    }

however, if you had a data structure in a util.final package and did an import final, I think you would have a class where the internals would be immutable and couldn't be extended. if it was mutable and just recalculated the hashCode on setValue() I think it'd be OK.  But I have not tested extensions and final imports.  What's here suits my needs nicely but I'd like you input.

Comment: @DavidUrry: Again, it's not something I'd want - because I want guarantees of actual immutability, not just "immutability of the bits exposed by string". It may be useful to you, but I'm personally really glad that `String` is final.

Answer (score 33):

I guess the closest you can come is making some class that implements [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). Most JDK string manipulation methods accept a CharSequence. [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for example. Combined with a good implementation of toString(), the various methods of String and valueOf(), you can come pretty close to a natural substitute.

Comment: This is a very good comment... possibly the best solution to OP's problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I've successfully used this to implement non-empty Strings, and do away with `.length() == 0` checks in my code!

Answer (score 6):

Now, there is a way. With [manifold](http://manifold.systems/docs.html#extension-classes) it's possible to extend every Java Class. Here is an example for String:

```
package extensions.java.lang.String;

import manifold.ext.api.*;

@Extension
public class MyStringExtension {

  public static void print(@This String thiz) {
    System.out.println(thiz);
  }

  @Extension
  public static String lineSeparator() {
    return System.lineSeparator();
  }
}
```

Can than be used as follow:

```
String name = "Manifold";
name.print();
String.lineSeparator();
```

Another example can be found here: https://jaxenter.com/manifold-code-generator-part-2-151762.html

Notice, that manifold is still alpha.

Comment: Very interesting, indeed!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot extend a class that is marked as final.  You can use composition to either put a String object inside or you can hand roll your own version.  This can be accomplished via character arrays and the other magic that goes into creating String classes.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to directly inherit String class as it is final. Also wrapper classes java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Float, etc... are final.

Comment: This answer only covers standard inheritance - how about alternative approaches to replacing the equals method?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple Strings class that mimics java.lang.String and can be extended.  This is just to demonstrate the core implementation requirements behind String are not "mysterious" or "complicated".  And, you can use it to do things like create a password extension and manage strings more effectively.

Needs:

- native call to big-endian. (see private static native boolean
  isBigEndian();)
- other String methods.

> ```
>     package com.paintedintel.util;
>     
>     import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
>     
> /**
>  * 
>  * @author David Urry
>  * @date 2/8/2020
>  * 
>  * Strings is a light weight string implementation based on StringUTF16.
>  * It's sole purpose is to create a system where strings can be extended
>  * so that the type of string can be extended without the weight of carrying
>  * extra object references.  
>  * 
>  * Strings extension is important for 2 reasons:
>  * 1) The extra object reference slows the code down by a factor of 50% making 
>  *    a 10X speed improvement only 5X.  As the object of looking at/comparing and
>  *    otherwise managing strings is expensive.
>  * 2) The code understanding benefits greatly from understanding the type of string
>  *    you are working with (Name, Value, Field, InitValue, Comment...).  The constant
>  *    evaluation of List<String> for example is greatly simplified when observing
>  *    List<Field> instead.
>  *    
>  * This problem was also greatly simplified by working with Type, Domain, Datum,
>  * StreamDomain, StreamCase and other objects as complex objects.
>  */
>
> public class Strings {
>   final byte[] value;
>     /** Cache the hash code for the string */
>     private int hash; // Default to 0
>  
>   protected Strings(String value){
>       if (value != null) {
>           this.value = value.getBytes();
>           this.hash = value.hashCode();
>       } else {
>           this.value = new byte[0];
>           this.hash = 0;
>       }
>   }
>   
>   Strings(byte[] value){
>       this.value = value;
>       this.hash = Strings.hashCode(value);
>   }
>   
>   @Override
>   public String toString() {
>       return new String(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
>   }
>   
>   public String str() {
>       return toString();
>   }
>   
>   public boolean equals(String str) {
>       return (str == null)?((value == null || this.length() == 0)?true:false):str.hashCode() == value.hashCode();
>   }
>   
>   public boolean eq(String str) {
>       return equals(str);
>   }
>   
>   byte[] getBytes() {
>       return value;
>   }
>   
>   int getHash() {
>       return hash;
>   }
>   
>   public int length() {
>       return value.length >> 1;
>   }
>   
>   /**
>    * this is based on StringUTF16 
>    * @param value
>    * @return
>    */
>   synchronized public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
>         int h = 0;
>         int length = value.length >> 1;
>         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>             h = 31 * h + getChar(value, i);
>         }
>         return h;
>     }
>     
>     // intrinsic performs no bounds checks
>   synchronized static char getChar(byte[] val, int index) {
>         assert index >= 0 && index < length(val) : "Trusted caller missed bounds check";
>         index <<= 1;
>         return (char)(((val[index++] & 0xff) << HI_BYTE_SHIFT) |
>                       ((val[index]   & 0xff) << LO_BYTE_SHIFT));
>     }
>
>     //private static native boolean isBigEndian();
>
> //    private static boolean isBigEndian() {
> //        //as of 2018 there are no major BigEndian systems left.
> //        // This is because it's less processing to convert & work with
> //        // Little-Endian.
> //        return false;
> //    }
>     
>     static final int HI_BYTE_SHIFT = 0;
>     static final int LO_BYTE_SHIFT = 8;
> //    static {
> //        if (isBigEndian()) {
> //            HI_BYTE_SHIFT = 8;
> //            LO_BYTE_SHIFT = 0;
> //        } else {
> //            HI_BYTE_SHIFT = 0;
> //            LO_BYTE_SHIFT = 8;
> //        }
> //    }
>     
>     synchronized public static int length(byte[] value) {
>         return value.length >> 1;
>     }
> }
> ```